# Writing to an XML File in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have an XML file of which I have an element as shown;

```
"<Event start="2011.12.12 13:45:00:0000" end="2011.12.12 13:47:00:0000" anon="89"/>"
```

I want to add another attribute "comment" and write it to this XML File giving;

```
"<Event start="2011.12.12 13:45:00:0000" end="2011.12.12 13:47:00:0000" anon="89" comment=""/>"
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks, Matt

Comment: There's a fully working example in my answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9588830/898289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setAttribute method to add attribute,

```
// Add an attribute
element.setAttribute("newAttrName", "attrValue");
```

Use the following method to write to XML file,

```
// This method writes a DOM document to a file
public static void writeXmlFile(Document doc, String filename) {
    try {
        // Prepare the DOM document for writing
        Source source = new DOMSource(doc);

        // Prepare the output file
        File file = new File(filename);
        Result result = new StreamResult(file);

        // Write the DOM document to the file
        Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        xformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :D

It is now completed!

Answer (score 2):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
Document document = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlFile);

Element eventElement = (Element)document.getElementsByTagName("Event").item(0);
eventElement.setAttribute("comment", "");
```

FYI: I've use DOM framework here `org.w3c.dom.*`

Answer (score 0):

Parse the file, add the attribute and write it back to disk.

There is plenty of frameworks that can do this. The DOM framework in Java is probably the first thing you should look at.

Comment: I have parsed all the elements of the xml file and I have tried to setAttribute("comment", ""). but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM, as suggested in previous answers, is certainly reasonable for this particular problem, which is relatively simple.

However, I have found that JDOM is generally much easier to use when you want to parse and/or modify XML files. Its basic approach is to load the entire file into an easy to use data structure. This works well unless your XML file is very very large.

For more info go to http://www.jdom.org/